# Not able to read All event from Merged Flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to Project Reactor, I am trying to implement following use case.
I want to merge 2 different flux and want to read all the event. But Thing is it seem my main thread is not waiting for all the event

```
    @Test
public void testMerge() {
    Flux <String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); // Flux<String>
    Flux <String> stringFlux1 = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("D", "E", "F")); // Flux<String>
    Flux <String> stringFlux2 = Flux.merge(stringFlux, stringFlux1).log();
    stringFlux2.subscribe();
}
```

> Output
> onNext Event D
> onNext Event E
> onNext Event F

I am only able to recevie above 3 event, not all event.

By observing this behavior, subscribe seems to be async operation so main thread is not waiting for its completion. I am trying to use reactor core lib in my project. Can anyone please help me with this. I want to read all event in some standard way like we do with Futures.

Comment: It's because the first Flux is async. The test method ends sooner than the Flux. If you only have this problem with testing, then look into StepVerifier provided by reactor-test library.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Thank you Martin for your response. When I was digging I came across Step Verifier. But my use case is to actually read all the event before existing the method. Is there any standard way to wait until completion or error is received?

Comment: Depending on your use case, one of the `block...` methods can do the job.

Comment: "But my use case is to actually read all the event before existing the method." if that is actually a prod requirement, I would challenge your need for reactive programming at all in that case... One of the most abused feature of Future is going back to blocking by calling `get()`. Why go async if you immediately abandon one of the main benefits? If you still find justification in doing that, `block()` method and its variants are the equivalent of `Future#get`.

Comment: @Simon I agree with you. This is not a prod requirement this is just part of exercise that I was doing while learning project Reactor. More like learning by doing. Thank you for your inputs they are appreciated.